# puppeteer evaluate functional with callback

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to evaluate a function with puppeteer but the callback is never firing (i am certain the host page is working as expected).

On the host page a listener works like:

```
DB.when('ready').execute(function(db){
  // DB can execute stuff
})
```

My puppeteer code attempts to fetch the db that is ready:

```
try {
  const dbhandle = await page.evaluate('DB.when("ready")');
  const result = await page.evaluate(db => db.execute, function(images) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(images));
    //do stuff with callback
  }, dbhandle);
    console.log('result', JSON.stringify(result));
} catch (e) {
    console.log('evaluate', e);
} finally {
    console.log('finally');
}
```

Am having no luck on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OMG I figured it out...

```
try {
  function fooBugger() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      DB.when('ready').execute(function(db) {
        if (db) {
          resolve(db.some_data);
        } else {
          reject('nope');
        }
      });
    });
  }
  const res = await page.evaluate(fooBugger);

  console.log('resultHandle', JSON.stringify(res));
} catch (e) {
  console.log('evaluateHandle', e);
} finally {
}
```

Comment: Nice work! Most of the stuff is promise-based, so wrapping callbacks with a promise is generally the way to go.

Comment: How would you go about passing a parameter to fooBugger though?

Comment: @NicholasSiegmundt you should ask a new question on stackoverflow and post the link here. Someone will answer it.